# $P^2 + P + 1$ is prime if $P$ is prime.

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

I just thought of it. I don't know if there is one such conjecture or a proven problem or if this is a new conjecture. If it already exists where can I find this problem. And most importantly how to prove it??

Comment: So is the question: "$P^2+P+1$ is prime for all prime $P$"?

Comment: It looks like you haven't tried so many values of $P$, since $$7^2+7+1 = 3\cdot 19.$$

Comment: An interesting question is whether there are infinite many primes $p$, such that $p^2+p+1$ is prime. The given claim can easily be disproven, as it was already done.

Comment: @jnyan In fact, a claim holding for $2$, $3$ and $5$ is far from being true for all primes. Perhaps you meant something else ?

Comment: @Peter: that is probably true but horribly difficult to prove. For instance, the existence of infinitely many primes of the form $k^2+1$ is still a conjecture.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio OK, interesting and probably out of reach, unless it can be proven that only finite many primes $p$ have the property that $p^2+p+1$ is prime.

Comment: I am sorry. Should have been more careful.

Comment: Another way to use this as a jumping off point is to move to the realm of probability theory, e.g. how often does $p\mapsto p^2+p+1$ preserve primality? This has the advantage of being numerically testable for some portion of the integers.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A053182.

Answer (score 5):

Set $P = 11$

$$P^2 + P + 1 = 121 + 11 + 1 = 133$$

$133$ is not prime, conjecture is not valid for all primes $P$.

Comment: True, and $P = 7$ is the smallest counter-example. We have that $P^2+P+1 = 49 + 7 + 1 = 57 = 3\cdot 19.$

Comment: Indeed! :D I chose $$11$ because I love that number.